# Registering AWSS3 configuration creating 5000+ memory leaks

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, memory-leaks, instruments

I've been trying to figure out for the past two days why this simple setting up of a AWSS3 configuration could possibly create 5000+ memory leaks.  This is the the code I have running in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // SetUp AWS Config
    let myIdentityPoolId = Constants.AWS_IDENTITY_POOL_ID
    let credentialsProvider: AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USWest2,
                                                                                           identityPoolId: myIdentityPoolId)
    if let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USWest2, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider) {
        AWSS3.register(with: configuration, forKey: "defaultKey")
    }

    return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().interceptApplication(application,
                                                                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

Using Instruments, I've tested removing all the code I shared (except for the return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().interceptApplication) and found that I get no memory leaks, but as soon as I add it back I end up with all the leaks... What gives?

If it helps, I'm wanting to list the objects of my AWS bucket which works with the following code:

```
 let listRequest: AWSS3ListObjectsRequest = AWSS3ListObjectsRequest()
    let s3 = AWSS3.s3(forKey: "defaultKey")

    listRequest.bucket = Constants.AWS_BUCKET
    listRequest.prefix = Constants.SPECIAL_PREFIX

    s3.listObjects(listRequest).continueWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in
}
```

Am I making an obvious mistakes?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app can work with these leaks then you can just file a bug [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues) and wait for the fixes.

It seems they are inheriting these leaks since long time as you can see [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/387) and [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/738). This issue [S3 multipart upload memory leak](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/738) is still open and marked as a bug so you need to wait until these are fixed.